# Not able to Display "owner name" & "whatID name" of Event in LWC, which is used in community

Tags: lightning-web-components, tasks, event

I want to display owner name in text format & What.Name in link format.

can any one please suggest.

**Apex :**

```
   public with sharing class FetchEventLWCController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Event getEventkRecord(Id eventId) 
    {
        Event event = [SELECT Subject, Event_Type__c, Id, OwnerId, Owner.Name, WhatId, What.Name, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, Description, Related_To_Account__c
                       FROM Event WHERE Id =: eventId LIMIT 1];

        System.debug('event'+event);
        return event;
    }
}
```

Using assignedto & relatedto in html to display it's value, currently it is showing me id of them. So I made following changes in html.

**html file:**

```
 <div class="formfield slds-list_horizontal slds-border_bottom">
                                <label>Assigned To</label>
                             <div class="a11">
                               <template if:true={event.data}> 
                                <template for:each={event.data} for:item="a">
                                   <p key={a.Id}>{a.Owner.Name}</p>
                                </template>
                               </template>
                             </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="formfield slds-border_bottom slds-list_horizontal">
                                <label>Related To</label>
                                <template if:true={event.data}> 
                                    <template for:each={event.data} for:item="a">
                                       <p key={a.Id}>{a.What.Name}</p>
                                    </template>
                                   </template>
                            </div>
```

and now it is giving me error as :

- This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. [t[Yn] is
  not a function] Failing descriptor:
  {markup://c:partnerEventRecordReadForm}

I refresh page as well but it did not work. can any one please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML you do not need to loop because you are working with a single event record.

In html write:

```
<div class="formfield slds-list_horizontal slds-border_bottom">
     <label>Assigned To</label>
     <p>{ownerName}</p>
</div>
<div class="formfield slds-border_bottom slds-list_horizontal">
     <label>Related To</label>
     <a href={url}>{whatName}</a>
</div>
```

In js write:

```
@api recordId;

@wire(getEventkRecord, { eventId: '$recordId' })
event;

get ownerName() {
    if (this.event && this.event.data) {
        return this.event.data.Owner.Name;
    }
}

get whatName() {        
    if (this.event && this.event.data) {
        return this.event.data.What.Name;
    }
}

get url() {
    if (this.event && this.event.data) {
        return '/'+ this.event.data.WhatId;
    }
}
```

Comment: It did work now, just wanted to check can we have link on whatname as it is shown on record.

Comment: Yes, you can write in HTML  like this:- <a href="your url goes here">{whatName}</a>

Comment: I have added something like this: 
<a href="/lightning/WhatId">{whatName}</a>
Is that correct? because it is not showing me error "Page not available"

Comment: Please see the edited answer.

Comment: still getting same error as page is not available

Comment: Then use NavigationMixin.Navigate to redirect to the record page on click of the link.